# Google Charts PHP wrapper - image mapping on charts

Tags: php, google-visualization, gchart

I use the gchartphp wrapper to create various graphs. I'd like to know if it support image maps like gcharts does?

Say I have a pie chart showing backup stats (success, failed, missing email). What I want is to be able to click on say, success and then get a list of all successful backups.

Is this possible with the gchartsphp wrapper or should I just go back to using the standard ghcarts URLs?

Comment: What does the gchartsphp wrapper documentation say?

Answer (score 0):

Even I have searched for such wrappers for building interaction Charts like shown [here](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/quick_start.html).

gChartPhp produces just the Chart URL for rendering in the webpage. It will not be interactive.

> A simple PHP Object wrapper for the Google Chart API. Should help
>   anyone who needs to automate the building of the Google Chart url.

To build interactive charts, you need to code your javascript by yourself.